# How to search all the files in a project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

According to a book I have ("Eclipse for Minor Geniuses" or something like that), you can search a set of files by selecting them and then choosing Search | Files.

This does not work for me, even when I have the "Selected Resources" radio button selected. Instead, it searches through every file in the Package Explorer, which contains several projects, including the Android APIDemo (massive).

Is there a way to select all the files in a project (other than clicking them all in turn) and then limiting the Search operation to those files only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I select just the project node in the package tree and choose the "Selected Resources" radio button, it searches all the files of the project in my version of Eclipse.

You can also select an arbitrary file in a project, and choose "Enclosing project".

Comment: Press Ctrl + H to bring up the search

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but it's possible to create some working sets and then search through that working set only.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. use Ctrl+Shift+R (ie Open Resource Popup).
2. type File Name in txt Box, eg. `*.jsp, scr`